# Javascript Redirect with SetTimout Not Working

Tags: javascript, gps, scope

Can't seem to get this javascript redirect to work?
Suggestions?

Should I maybe do it with a meta refresh and how?

```
// If we have a successful location update
function onGeoSuccess(event)
{
    document.getElementById("Latitude").value =  event.coords.latitude; 
    document.getElementById("Longitude").value = event.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById("location").href = "track.cfm?track=s&Lat=" + event.coords.latitude + "&Long=" + event.coords.longitude;

var redirectUrl = "track.cfm?track=s&Lat=" + event.coords.latitude + "&Long=" + event.coords.longitude; 

}

// If something has gone wrong with the geolocation request
function onGeoError(event)
{
    alert("Error code " + event.code + ". " + event.message);
}

function redirect() 
     { 
    window.location = redirectUrl; 
     } 
    setTimeout(redirect,15000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the *scope* of `redirectUrl` variable. You declared `redirectUrl` as local for `onGeoSuccess` function, so it *will be visible only inside of it*. For workaround ,you can put all this stuff:

```
function redirect() 
{ 
    window.location = redirectUrl; 
} 
setTimeout(redirect,15000);
```

inside of `onGeoSuccess` function, or make `redirectUrl` global, by removing `var` before `redirectUrl`:

```
     redirectUrl = "track.cfm?track=s&Lat="+...
//^-----no 'var'
```

Comment: Global variables? Poo, poo, poo.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of using global variables. There's almost always some way to adjust the scope, and looking at the code, it is not clear that `redirect()` is being called at the right time (on page load?) anyway. Why not do the `setTimeout()` *within* `onGeoSuccess()`, or call `redirect(redirectUrl)` from within that callback?

Comment: @JaredFarrish I am also not fan of using global variables, but in OP's context, it seems that all his/her functions are declared globally, so putting `var redirectUrl;` outside of `onGeoSuccess` functions, or avoiding `var` word before `redirectUrl="..."` is 'equivalent'.

Comment: Then *don't make it rely on a global variable*. Period. Seeing that it was accepted and taking `var` off was the interpreted solution, how often will the OP use a naive "just leave `var` off" approach? That's the problem with not giving a best practice approach, at least as a caveat. It's easy for beginner's to get a naive impression.

Comment: @JaredFarrish There is no problem with using global variables at all *in OP's context*. Don't talk globally and abstract.

Comment: *Don't talk globally and abstract.* I don't know what this means; I assume this is an accusation. As I said, it *looks* like `redirect(redirectUrl)` could be called from *within* `onGeoSuccess`. The attempt at discouraging global variables is at least as useful as the practice when dealing with situations like this, with someone who is not skilled enough to understand the basic syntax *and* it's considerations.

Comment: @JaredFarrish By "Don't talk globally and abstract", I meant "Be specific to current problem,not to global problems that global variables can cause.". And I suggest to you posting your own answer, where you could demonstrate the solution, and tell why it is more convenient. Cheers.

Comment: I disagree *with this approach* in your answer; hence, the comments. Moving on...

Comment: @JaredFarrish You have your own opinion, and that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `redirectUrl` in parent scope, and run `onGeoSuccess` function.

```
var redirectUrl;

function onGeoSuccess (event) {
  document.getElementById("Latitude").value =  event.coords.latitude; 
  document.getElementById("Longitude").value = event.coords.longitude;
  document.getElementById("location").href = "track.cfm?track=s&Lat=" + event.coords.latitude + "&Long=" + event.coords.longitude;

  redirectUrl = "track.cfm?track=s&Lat=" + event.coords.latitude + "&Long=" + event.coords.longitude; 

}

function onGeoError (event) {
  alert("Error code " + event.code + ". " + event.message);
}

function redirect () { 
  window.location = redirectUrl; 
} 

onGeoSuccess(...);
setTimeout(redirect, 15000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1) The redirect URL is being set by a function which, at least from the code you posted, is not being called

2) Even if it was called, `redirectUrl` is a local variable to that function, so the timeout cannot access it.

Always check the error console.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL relative and not absolute. 
Redirect url should be in the format: http://www.xyz.com?xyz=pqr

For example:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/" + "track.cfm?track=s&Lat=" + event.coords.latitude + "&Long=" + event.coords.longitude;
```

Also watch the scope of your `redirectUrl` variable, it is not visible in the timeout function.

Comment: The form `window.location.href` is not required, `window.location` will do, or even `location = url;`

Comment: I just verified, You are right Jared. (Corrected the emphasis in the answer)