# Javascript Continuous Redirect

Tags: javascript, gps

I have this page loading fine once...

Basically it is pulling a gps location, I then want it to do the redirect every 10 seconds to pull gps data again...

But it will not continually redirect every 10 seconds...

What up - by the looks of things it should...

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> 

// Get a single location update
function getLocationConstant()
{
    if(navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onGeoSuccess,onGeoError,{enableHighAccuracy:true,maximumAge:0});
    } else {
        alert("Your browser or device doesn't support Geolocation");
    }
}

// If we have a successful location update
function onGeoSuccess(event)
{
    document.getElementById("Latitude").value =  event.coords.latitude; 
    document.getElementById("Longitude").value = event.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById("location").href = "track2.cfm?track=s&GPSLat=" + event.coords.latitude + "&GPSLong=" + event.coords.longitude;

    redirectUrl = "track2.cfm?track=y&GPSLat=" + event.coords.latitude + "&GPSLong=" + event.coords.longitude; 

    gpslat = event.coords.latitude; 
    gpslong = event.coords.longitude; 

}

// If something has gone wrong with the geolocation request
function onGeoError(event)
{
    alert("Error code " + event.code + ". " + event.message);
}

function redirect() 
{ 
    window.location = redirectUrl; 
} 
setTimeout(redirect,10000); 

 </script>
```

Comment: It may be a scope issue. It appears that the redirectUrl may be local to its original function where its value was set. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Isn't this the same question as the one you asked earlier? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702088/javascript-redirect-with-settimout-not-working Then, as now, it's not clear how or indeed if the `onGeoSuccess` function is being called - crucial, because that's where the redirect string is set.

Comment: I'm trying to keep the issues seperate and not plug up the post - the redirect did work on previous - but won't continuously redirect with new gps data

Comment: Your code does not show how getLocationConstant()
 is called. Maybe it is a better idea to call getLocationConstant()
per interval instead reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues here.

1) like jay c says, one is that the callback is only run once. To fix that, you could either do what is said with setInterval, or, at the end of redirect, you just set up the timer again…

```
function redirect() {
    window.location = redirectUrl;
    setTimeout(redirect, 10000);
}
```

2) the URL is always the same if the location hasn’t changed. The browser may notice this and not refresh the url. You could force it with some window reload action, or you could guarantee the url freshness by attaching the timestamp to it.

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var milliseconds = currentTime.getTime();

redirectUrl = "track2.cfm?track=y&GPSLat=" + event.coords.latitude + "&GPSLong=" + event.coords.longitude + "&time=" + milliseconds;
```